# Renamed and deleted folders in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I have renamed a folder `Forms` > `View`

This is what it looks like in Visual Studio:

[image]

And for some strange reason this is still used:

[image]

And If I try to access the `view` apparently I have 1 form created in there.. and the rest does not exists.

But the `using Technical_Application.Forms;` has all of it, expect the new form I created.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: `{ }` seems to be a [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/). By renaming folder you didn't change namespace.

Comment: Have you renamed the namespaces within each file in the renamed folder?

Comment: @Sinatr Im confused, namespace remains the same?

Comment: @Alejandro I have added a image at the end of the question.. what do I need to replace there?

Comment: Namespace have nothing to do with folders. A namespace is defined when you use `namespace SomeNamespace{ .... }` in code. You can have multiple namespaces in the same file although that's not very common

Comment: `Login` is not a part of `Forms` namespace in screenshot. Since you are typed `using` the intellisense is smart enough to hide `Login` from that list, but somewhere you still have `Forms` namespace in your project.

Comment: Have you tried, close SLN, delete `OBJ` and `BIN` folders, reopen sln, sometime VS gets drunk

Comment: @Rippo haha! will try now

Comment: @Rippo Why would that help? Namespaces are not folders, and folders are not namespaces. VS is just helpful in that it generates namespaces around the folders when you create classes. It doesn't do anything to maintain that though.

Comment: No it didnt work deleteing the obj and bin. But within `obj>debug` this shows `Technical_Application.Forms.Dashboard.resources`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, when creating folders in solution and then nested cs-files using VS context menu the files will have namespace matching folder structure by default (so folder name *has to do* something with namespace sometimes). This is from where OP confusion comes I think. `Login` wasn't originally created in `Forms` folder, it doesn't have namespace `Technical_Application.Forms` or perhaps it was edited.

Comment: @Alejandro is correct... u need to change all namespace which use the "one you dont want" then close all files and close vs and reopen.. Forms will no longer be there

Answer (score 1):

> But the `using Technical_Application.Forms;` has all of it, expect the new form I created.
> How do I fix this?

To add `Login` to `Forms` namespace you need to change

```
 namespace Technical_Application
 {
```

to

```
 namespace Technical_Application.Forms
 {
```

in **all** `Login` class sources (since it's `partial class`). Don't forget designer-generated file and if you forget - no worry, compiler will remind you ;)

---

You will have to do it now everytime you add a new form to `View` folder using wizard, since VS is using current folder structure to generate namespace for a new file. As a workaround consider to keep empty `Forms` folder to create new forms there and then simply drag-and-drop them into `View`.